# Write/update data via ADO to closed Excel workbook

Tags: excel, ado, vba

I'm trying to change the number in a closed Excel workbook using ADO. I found the below code written in 2015 by L42. But the procedure stops with the error "No value given for one or more required parameters". I can't find where something is missing!

```
Sub ChangeNum()
Dim con As ADODB.Connection, rec As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sqlstr As String, datasource As String
  Set con = New ADODB.Connection: Set rec = New ADODB.Recordset
  datasource = "D:\DropBox\TraderShare\TraderNum.xlsx"
Dim sconnect As String
  sconnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
             "Data Source=" & datasource & ";" & _
             "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
  con.Open sconnect
  sqlstr = "UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET [Number] = ""16900"" WHERE [ID] = INum"
  rec.Open sqlstr, con, adOpenUnspecified, adLockUnspecified 'adLockOptimistic , adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
  con.Close
  Set rec = Nothing: Set con = Nothing
End Sub
```

Grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I found the fault! The sqlstr should be written:

```
sqlstr = "UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET [Number] = ""16900"" WHERE [ID] = ""INum"""
```

It's the exclamation marks that matters! I don't know why it's required in this way, if the exclamation marks are required to concatenate different parts of the string. But they look to be out of sequence, there's 1 too much in the end!

Comment: Exclamation marks would make a difference... but you meant quotation marks, which probably make more of a difference. Good job answering your own question.

Answer (score 0):

The usual reason for this error is a missing or misspelled value. I would go over the SQL statement specifically and see whats off

Comment: Yes, Doug, that's exactly what I'm asking for. But I've very little knowledge in SQL and ADO, the reason why I'm asking for help! As you see there are few lines of code and the spelling is of course what I checked first. The error is trigged at "rec.Open sqlstr, con, adOpenUnspecified, adLockUnspecified. I can't find any more **required** parameters for the Open statement.